# problematic(s) (noun, not adjective) vs. problem

Tags: differences

This question differs from [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/61222/50720), where answererss nix 'problematic' as a noun. But the following academics (all fluent in English) use it: are they  wrong? If not, how do these cognates differ?

1. Richard Posner's  highly cited book is called [*The Problematics of Moral and Legal Theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Posner#Books).
2. Nikolas Rose and Peter Miller. *[Political Power beyond the State: Problematics of Government](http://www.jstor.org/stable/591464?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)*

> ABSTRACT
>
> This paper sets out an approach to the analysis of political power in
> terms of **problematics [bold mine]** of government. It argues against an over
> valuation of the 'problem of the State' in political debate and social
> theory. A number of conceptual tools are suggested for the analysis
> of the many and varied alliances between political and other
> authorities that seek to govern economic activity, social life and
> individual conduct. Modern political rationalities and governmen-

3. *The Idea of Labour Law*. [p. 324.](https://books.google.com/books?id=f0pF0T4o5MQC&pg=PA324&lpg=PA324&dq=%22As+long+as+labour+law+is+explained+by+reference+to+the+relationship%22&source=bl&ots=VjkNmjMtqL&sig=4RG85Orl3jznYXAS7rRVa_5fTH0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO_4_G9cPYAhXs7IMKHS3zBqsQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22As%20long%20as%20labour%20law%20is%20explained%20by%20reference%20to%20the%20relationship%22&f=false) Author: [Guy Mundlak](https://en-law.tau.ac.il/profile/mundlak), LLM (Waived), SJD (Harvard Law).

> As long as labour law is explained by reference to the relationship between labour
> and capital, only some aspects of labour law's **problematics [bold mine]** are highlighted. It is
> therefore essential to recognize the third function of labour law. In speculative
> fashion, I would like to suggest that the third function has often been concealed by
> labour's side. Recognizing the distributive impact of labour law within labour's side
> has often been left to free-market advocates.

Comment: The answers and comments on the question you refer to clearly say that *problematics* is a mistake often made by writers fluent in other languages who assume that the word exists in English. How does finding examples of writers fluent in other languages and in English who use the word affect that?

Comment: but @TimLymington, "snowclones" {again, I don't know if that's exactly the right term here} can't be mistakes.   If I say unto you, "Tim, this is a book on [meshmatiks](http://amazon.com/Mathematics-Programming-Computer-Graphics-Third/dp/1435458869)," it's absolutely clear what I mean.  it's completely clear to me now how "problematiks" is used amongst writers in that field.

Comment: (It's just occurred to me that snowclones eventually just become "suffixes".  Is that right?!  :) )

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. 'Problematics' is defined in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/problematics) and at Dictionary.com. This is general reference.

Comment: Don't assume that because they are academics they write English well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's just a (ubiquitous) form in, let's say, "business/academic English" today.

**-matics** is pretty much agreed on for 10, 20 years?

You've surely heard of "infomatics" and/or "informatics" ( [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informatics) ).

I've seen dozens and dozens of "-matics" words.

"Infomatics" is the most common one I can think of - you can literally get a degree in info[r]matics.

I've probably used "-matics" words many times.  So, something like "meshmatics" when talking with colleagues (to do with 3D mesh) or "touchmatics" (the touch aspect of phone/etc programming).

"-matics" helps you clarify that you mean, let us say, **"the science of" the topic in question**.

Rather than the practical-level concerns. (All of this is obvious to any native English speaker.)

"-matics" is a ubiquitous "snowclone-like" form.

(I've given up trying to know exactly what a "snowclone" is - but the "-matics" thing is something like a snowclone!)

To me the two sentences,

> ...power in terms of problematics of government.
>
> ...some aspects of labour law's problematics are highlighted.

are quite obvious.  If I know nothing about that field (and I don't) it's obvious what it means; if I was in that field I'd assume that it's now a common term if I hadn't already been using it.

Note - for me, the first example there is used in the wrong way: it should be more like "power in terms of government problematics."

---

BTW I like using the "k" in -matiks. It makes it more clear your using the "-matics" snowclone (/whatever :/ ) and it reflects the German origin.

Comment: Actually, I suppose "computer science" (a confusing term) should be called "softmatics" or "softwarematics".  (A word already used zillion of times for company names.)